# WPF Bindings TreeView Issue with view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm simply trying to bind my tree view in xaml but for some reason the list does not seem to be showing, I have attached the code. Any help would be great.

Many thanks

```
class Item
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public List<string> TreeItems { get; set; }
    public List<Item> SubItems { get; set; }
}
```

this is the view model

```
    public StoreLibraryViewModel()
    {
        this.DisplayName = "hierarchy Library";
        TreeItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        string[] data = new string[]{
            "Warwick","Birmingham",
        };
        Item item = new Item()
        {
            Header = "Region",
            TreeItems = new List<string>(data)
        };

        TreeItems.Add(new Item()
        {
            Header = "Region 1",
            SubItems = new List<Item>(new Item[] { item }),
            TreeItems = new List<string>(data)
        });
        TreeItems.Add(new Item()
        {
            Header = "Region 2",
            SubItems = new List<Item>(new Item[] { item }),
            TreeItems = new List<string>(data)
        });

        TreeItems.Add(new Item()
        {
            Header = "Region 3",
            SubItems = new List<Item>(new Item[] { item }),
            TreeItems = new List<string>(data)
        });
    }
    ObservableCollection<Item> TreeItems { get; set; }
```

this is the XAML

```
TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                <Expander Header="{Binding Header}">
                    <ItemsControl Margin="25,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}" />
                </Expander>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

All I seem to be displaying is a empty tree view, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Where do you set  your DataContext?

Comment: If you are not sure, what is happening in your visual tree, maybe use some WPF debugging tools: WPF debugger from VS 2015, or great app called Snoop.

Comment: cheers for the quick response guys, how should I define the DataContext?

Comment: In the code-behind file where you have the xaml, just write in the constructor 'DataContext = new YourViewModel();'

Comment: Hi Mkdavor ive tried this and also made the collection of Items Bindiable, still have a problem, thanks for the advice

Comment: @agneovotom, change  ObservableCollection<Item> TreeItems { get; set; } to **public**  ObservableCollection<Item> TreeItems { get; set; }

Comment: I will write an answer below, check it out.

Comment: cheers dude, I needed to develop this as shown as I do not want to create a code behind for my XAML.CS

Comment: Setting DataContext in code behind is not breaking the MVVM pattern, don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to assign your datacontext in the xaml code like this:

```
<Window ....
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myStoreLibraryViewModelNameSpace"
        ....
        />
     <Window.DataContext>
        <local:StoreLibraryViewModel />
     </Window.DataContext>
   ....
```

where myStoreLibraryViewModelNameSpace is the namespace in which **StoreLibraryViewModel** is located

Answer (score -1):

You should add:

```
DataContext = new StoreLibraryViewModel();
```

Then you need to make  your ObservableCollection TreeItems { get; set; } public

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> TreeItems { get; set; }
```

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: thanks so much, I noticed that as soon as I made my observable collection public everything was working, totally missed it! been a long day, thanks for all the help

Comment: I added DataContext="{Binding}"  directly to my treeview if this helps

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted? I tried this in a new WPF project, it works, and I also posted a screenshot... Whayt is so wrong that I would get a downvote?